# C# - Strange behavior while parsing an XElement

Tags: c#, parsing, xelement

I've observed a strange behavior by parsing a string to a XElement.

First, here is the XML I want to parse :

```
<return value="0">
    <resultset>
        <meta>
            <column type="char(30)"></column>
        </meta>
        <datarow>
            <datacol>
                <![CDATA[master]]>
            </datacol>
        </datarow>
    </resultset>
</return>
```

Now the code :

```
            try
            {
                xmlResult = XElement.Parse(
                    _UTF8Encoder.GetString(_responseBytes.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)_responseBytes.Length),
                    LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
            }
            catch
            {
                xmlResult = XElement.Parse(
                   _UTF8Encoder.GetString(_responseBytes.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)_responseBytes.Length),
                   LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
            }
```

I do exactly the same thing in the try and catch block.

Sometime the try block raises an XmlException ("Root element is missing."), but the catch block (doing exactly the same thing) doesn't throw it and parse the string correctly.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks !

[EDIT]

Here is the whole method code :

```
private TcpClient _client;
private NetworkStream _clientStream;
private MemoryStream _responseBytes;
private readonly UTF8Encoding _UTF8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    private XElement Receive()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        XElement xmlResult;
        Encoding serverEncoding = this.Task.Server.Encoding;

        // Reading result
        while (true)
        {
            _responseBytes = new MemoryStream();

            try
            {
                IAsyncResult e = _clientStream.BeginRead(buffer,
                    0,                                              // Begin
                    BUFFER_SIZE,                                    // Length
                    new AsyncCallback(OnBeginRead),                 // Callback used
                    new SocketAsyncState(_clientStream, buffer));   // Passing buffer to callback

                e.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();    // Wait until data are in pipe

                if (((SocketAsyncState)e.AsyncState).HasError)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException();
                }

                // Try to convert to a XElement, if fail, redo all process.
                _responseBytes.Position = 0;

                try
                {
                    xmlResult = XElement.Parse(
                        _UTF8Encoder.GetString(_responseBytes.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)_responseBytes.Length),
                        LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                }
                catch
                {
                    xmlResult = XElement.Parse(
                       _UTF8Encoder.GetString(_responseBytes.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)_responseBytes.Length),
                       LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                }

                // Result 100% retrieved : quit loop
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                if (ex is ObjectDisposedException
                    || ex is XmlException)
                {
                    while (!IsConnected) { Wait(); }   // Wait that the network comes back
                    SendSyn();                         // Relaunch process
                }
            }
        }

        // Result 100% retrieved : send ACK to Socket
        SendAck();

        return xmlResult;
    }

    private void OnBeginRead(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SocketAsyncState state = ar.AsyncState as SocketAsyncState;
        byte[] nextBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int numberOfBytesReaded;
        Encoding serverEncoding = this.Task.Server.Encoding;

        try
        {
            numberOfBytesReaded = state.Stream.EndRead(ar);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            ((SocketAsyncState)ar.AsyncState).HasError = true;
            // Quit
            return;
        }

        // While data are available, read next buffer (recursive call to this method)
        if (state.Stream.DataAvailable && state.Stream.CanRead)
        {
            state.Stream.BeginRead(nextBuffer,
                0,
                BUFFER_SIZE,
                new AsyncCallback(OnBeginRead),
                new SocketAsyncState(state.Stream, nextBuffer));
        }

        // Default C# strings are in UTF-8, so convert stream only if needed
        if (serverEncoding.CodePage != _UTF8Encoder.CodePage)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Convert(serverEncoding,
                _UTF8Encoder,
                state.Data.TakeWhile((b) => b != '\0').ToArray());

            _responseBytes.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            _responseBytes.Write(state.Data, 0, numberOfBytesReaded);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown us what `_responseBytes` is, but one suggestion springs to mind: if it's being populated asynchronously (e.g. via an async web request) then maybe the first attempt occurs before the data is present, but by the time the catch block executes, the data has arrived.

(Obviously if this is the case, the solution is *not* to use this sort of catch block but to fix the timing.)

EDIT: Okay, I think I possibly see the problem. It's here:

```
e.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

I suspect that will wait until the read has occurred at the socket level, but *before the callback is invoked*. Your code is assuming it waits until the callback has *completed*.

So what's happening (and this is still just a guess) is:

- On your main thread, you kick off the operation and wait for it to complete
- The data is read
- `WaitOne()` returns in the main thread and the callback is invoked on the thread-pool thread at the same time
- You try to parse the data from the memory stream in the main thread...
- ... and *then* the callback actually writes the data to the memory stream
- ... and *then* you have a second try at parsing, which succeeds because the data is now there

Comment: Please see the edit. You're right all is done asynchronously but seems to be very strange that the MemoryStream isn't populated ...

Comment: @Arnaud: Where is `_responseBytes` being written to? What is `buffer`? There's a bunch of code we still don't have yet. If you could edit your question to a short but *complete* program it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for interesting, see the edit, I've added more code (method where _responseBytes is being written).

Comment: @Arnaud: I've edited my answer with a guess as to why this is happening.

Comment: @Jon: I've observed this behavior yes. I've tried on a biggest buffer to receive and the WaitOne release the lock before all is read, but how can I fix that? Is there a simple way or should I add a ManualResetEvent by myself? Thanks for reply :)

Comment: @Arnaud: It depends what the bigger picture is. Given that you're blocking, it's not clear to me why you're using asynchronous operations in the first place. I'd also say that the way you're basically "looping until you've got a whole XML document" isn't a very clean way of detecting completion. Typically you'd use a length-prefixed message, or a delimiter, or read until the end of the stream.

Comment: Ok, I used asynchronous read to do the read in background, how you would write this other? :?

Comment: @Arnaud: In what way is this doing the read in the background? You're calling `WaitOne` which blocks until it's done... you're getting all of the pain of asynchronous IO with none of the benefits.

Comment: Hum, yes you're totally right, I'm on the wrong way :(, I need to perform this part again to be more secured and avoid useless stuff... Thanks for the help provided.